# When should I use Thread but DispatchQueue on iOS?

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

In my daily work, I can handle some multi-thread condition using GCD, but I also see the usage of  thread in project, example, log module use thread but queue in my project. I just can't understand why. There is some benefit to use thread than GCD? How should I choose?

Comment: A thread is in your control entirely and does what you want. GCD is a queue that does things that are put there, either one at a time or concurrently. They have very different use cases and it's quite broad topic to start explaining everything. In general, if you need to run a unit of work and possible not care about when it finishes, just queue it. If you want some code to run concurrently all the time entirely under your control, thread is probably what you want.

Comment: Apple gives extensive guidance here (the short answer is you won't use threads by hand in iOS; in the 11 years since GCD came out, I've used (NS)Thread about 3 times, and 2 of them were mistakes I later removed): https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1

Comment: (But @SamiKuhmonen is correct and I'm not disagreeing. In some real-time operations like audio it can make sense to take full control with a long-lived thread. But IMO, if you actually need threads, you should first be working in C++. If your code makes sense in Swift or ObjC with ARC and sloppy performance promises, then you probably don't need the control of a manually managed thread.)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thanks, I have read apple document, and I known the different between thread and GCD. I just can't find conditions using thread but GCD. Your answer helped me a lot.

Comment: Your code that is using threads outside of the context of GCD might be cross-platform code. Or code that pre-dates GCD. Or code that has some legitimate use of threads. But it’s very uncommon to see explicit thread code in a GCD world. We obviously can’t help you decide whether the use of threads was legitimate or just poor programming, without seeing what the code is doing. Feel free to add representative example of what the thread code is doing in your question. In the absence of that, it’s very hard to answer this question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pthread is often used by cross-platform code, so you are quite likely to run into it when you include third-party libraries in your code, and usually don't touch it.

Using NSThread would be very, very, very rare. Except for calling [NSThread isMainThread] to determine whether your code is running on the main thread or on a background thread. Unless you have a real good reason to do otherwise, use GCD. Mostly because it is so much easier to use that suddenly you will use multithreading in places where you would never have used it otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So, there is not a condition using thread but GCD on iOS?